# Hadoop Hive Date String to UTC Time SQL

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a String column in my database which looks like

```
07/12/2019 04:17:08 PM
```

I use the function

```
cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(myfield, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as timestamp)as mytime
```

This gives me the result of

```
2019-07-12 04:17:08.0
```

I want the result to be in utc format and look something like

```
2019-07-12 16:17:08.
```

How can i change this to be in utc format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `aaa` to parse the AM/PM in datetime. `from_unixtime` converts it to `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` by default where the hour part is 24 hour format.

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(myfield, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aaa'))
```